# Is it more efficient to build the "visual tree" in xaml rather than programmatically?

Tags: wpf, performance, user-controls, wpf-controls

I’m working on a WPF application with a tabbed MDI interface. Basically, the user clicks a menu item and this creates and adds a new tab. A new 'MyUserControl' is created and set to be the tab's Content. Something like this:

```
    private void MenuItem_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.TabControl.Items.Add(new TabItem() { Content = new MyUserControl() });
    }
```

MyUserControl is composed of several nested controls (approx. 8 controls). When this approach is wired up to the actual control, the performance is unacceptable.

Unless I’m losing my mind, I’ve noticed that the performance hit seems to be much less when declaring the tab and content in xaml ahead of time and simply toggling the tab item's Visibility property:

```
    <Controls:TabControl x:Name="TabControl" Grid.Row="1">
        <Controls:TabControl.Items>
            <Controls:TabItem x:Name="MyTabItem" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Controls:MyUserControl x:Name="MyUserControl" />
            </Controls:TabItem>
        </Controls:TabControl.Items>
    </Controls:TabControl>
```

and

```
    private void MenuItem_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.MyTabItem.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Can anyone explain this? Is it really more efficient to build the "visual tree" in xaml rather than programmatically? Or has the performance hit in my second approach just been moved to the overall form's load instead of when the menu item is clicked as in the first approach?

The second approach definitely seems to perform much better. Any thoughts?

Comment: from your comments, it seems your example is much-simplified from your real code.  Is the complexity that you have a huge number of child controls, or is it that you're doing a lot of data work in the control load?

Comment: Definitely. I was trying to keep the example simple. Based on the comments below, I believe the complexity is related to the number of controls/styles. The control load event handlers for all the child controls are really not that complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no more efficient to declare it it xaml. I think you are correct in thinking that the performance hit has been moved to the form load.

If it is taking too long to load, maybe it is doing too much work in its constructor. See if you can minimize the work done during the loading of the control.

Otherwise, if the problem is just the sheer amount of controls in the user control, maybe you could keep a fully loaded tab in memory until it is ready to be used. Once the user clicks the menu item, add it to the tabcontrol and then start loading a new one in a background thread.

Comment: Xaml is converted to Baml before distribution, so there is no runtime parsing.

Comment: I commented out basically all of the logic in the constructors for all of the controls and this did seem to make a difference. Thanks! Where's the optimal place for "initialization logic" such as this? The UserControl_Loaded event handler? On related note, after removing the constructor logic, there was still a noticeable delay. After running it through the profiler, System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent was the "bottle neck". Is there any way to speed this up, or is it directly related to the number of controls on the screen?

Comment: LoadComponent loads the control and all children controls from baml. This means creating instances of the objects in the markup. If you already removed all the constructor logic and this still takes a signigicant time then there's not really a way to speed it up. You should think about loading it early in a background thread before it is needed so that it just needs to be rendered when the user clicks the menu item. Is that feasible?

Comment: regarding the initialization logic, it really depends on what you are doing. What logic was in your constructor? Try to decide whether each user control really needs all of the initialization (for example make sure that static reference data is not being loaded from a db for each control, instead of being shared). If it is still a problem, determine whether all logic needs to be done before the user can start on the form, or if some logic can be done in a background thread.

Comment: @saus: you need to be careful about loading controls in background threads, because they need to be created on the main `Dispatcher` thread unless you want some real headaches.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. I will look into loading the control ahead of time and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @dan yep good point, I didn't think about that. in that case I think refactoring the initialization logic is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you moved the performance hit to the initialization of the Window. Even collapsed, the instance of the `UserControl` has been made - you've added it explicitly to the `TabControl`. Opening a tag in xaml is the same thing as saying `new`. Collapsed controls have to be constructed because even if you can't see it or interact with it on screen, other controls can have bindings to it and code-behind can work with the instance.

If you prefer your first approach, try caching the instance of the `UserControl` if you can instead of creating a new one each time.

Comment: How would you cache a UserControl instance?  That's a big question, so what keywords can I google for the specific technique in your mind?  I've googled "WPF cache UserControl", but did not find anything that seems to apply here.

Comment: Hi @ZachMierzejewski. It very much depends on how you've structured your project and if you are using an MVVM framework of some kind. I am currently using Caliburn Micro and with it you can implement an interface in your ViewModel which allows you the opportunity to keep a reference to the instance of the view which it will re-use as necessary. This comes with caveats though; the same view cannot be shown in two places at the same time, it'll also only work if you manage your ViewModel instances correctly. You'll have to give me more info to help.